# $(X_n)$ transient Markov chain with transition probability matrix $P = \|P_{ij}\|$. Define $u(i) = \sum P_{i0}^{(n)}$. Then $u(X_n)$ is submartingale

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, martingales

Let $(X_n), n \geq 0$ be a transient Markov chain on the non-negative integers with transition probability matrix $P = \|P_{ij}\|$. Define $u(i) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} P_{i0}^{(n)}$.

Then $u(X_k)$ is submartingale.

My attempt:

Let $\Gamma = [X_1 = i_1, \dots, X_k = i_k]$.

We just need to show that $\mathbb{E}[u(X_{k+1})\textbf{1}_\Gamma] = \mathbb{E}[u(X_{k})\textbf{1}_\Gamma]$

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[u(X_{k+1})\textbf{1}_\Gamma] &= \sum_{j=0}^{+\infty} \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} P_{j0}^{(n)} \textbf{1}_\Gamma \textbf{1}_{X_{k+1}=j}\right] \\
&= \sum_{j=0}^{+\infty} \mathbb{E} \left[\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \sum_{i=0}^{+\infty} P_{ji}P_{i0}^{(n-1)}\textbf{1}_\Gamma \textbf{1}_{X_{k+1}=j}\right] \\
&= \sum_{j=0}^{+\infty} \mathbb{E} \left[\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty} P_{ji} \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} P_{i0}^{(n-1)} \textbf{1}_\Gamma \textbf{1}_{X_{k+1}=j}\right]
\end{align}

As we have a Markov chain, for a fixed $j$, $\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty} P_{ji}  = 1$.

Thus:

$$
\mathbb{E}[u(X_{k+1})\textbf{1}_{\Gamma}] = \sum_{j=0}^{+\infty} \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} P_{i0}^{(n-1)}\textbf{1}_\Gamma \textbf{1}_{X_{k+1}=j}\right]
$$

How can I continue from here? I made some more steps,but it not lead me to anything...

Comment: The very last equation in your question is not correct; note that the sum $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P_{i0}^{(n-1)} 1_{\Gamma} 1_{X_{k+1}=j}$ depends on $i$ and so you cannot use $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} P_{ji}$ to get rid of the summation over $i$. (Just have a look at this last equation; there is still an $i$ in there.)

Comment: Yeah... That's true! My mistake!

Comment: You'll have better luck showing that $u(X_k)$ is a *supermartingale*. As a start: $u(i) =1_{\{i=0\}}+\sum_jP_{ij}u(j)$.